# Jenkins : Transfer file to linux server (filtering windows character from files)

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

We need to transfer files from Jenkin server(with contain GIT local repository) to Linux server. We are using the 'Publish over SSH' to accomplish this task, but unfortunately our GIT repository contains windows character (^M / CR+LF(\r\n)) in every file, which is creating trouble in executing the files in the Linux server.

In manual deployment, we transfer files using WinSCP text mode (for most of our extensions) rather default binary format. This process is working fine for us.

Could anyone suggest if we have some plugin in which we can specify the file transfer mode ( for some extensions).